# A solar circuit to charge a battery with a non-standard voltage

Tags: integrated-circuit, charger, solar-charge-controller

I have a Pb battery I pulled from one of my sons toys (no longer being used of course) and it's specs are as follows.

```
Voltage charge
Cycle Use: 7.2v - 7.5v
Standby use: 6.8v - 6.9v

Initial current
Cycle use: 1.1A
```

I'd like to hook this up to a solar panel and a charge controller but all of the ones for sale are mostly 12V solar charge systems. I have a spare 20W solar panel but no charge controller.

I consider myself pretty basic at electronics, at best I'm able to hook up pre-made IC's but not at a level where I can make my own circuit, yet.

Should I attempt to make a circuit or use a pre-made IC? If so, which one?

Thanks everyone

Comment: what is non-standard about the voltage?

Comment: Those voltages are standard for lead acid 7v batteries. Panel can connect via current limiting resistor if a  means is provided of limitingv Vmax

Comment: You can find a "6V solar charge controller" on the usual sources with the appropriate search term. These are generally intended for the 3 cell lead acid batteries your voltages describe

Comment: Lead acid batteries exist in nominal 2V, 4V, 6V, 8V, (theoretically 10V but never seen), 12V, etc. nominally 2.00V/cell. Fully charged they are about 2.1V per cell, when being charged they are at 2.2-2.4V per cell.  Your voltages don't make much sense as a lead-acid battery, as it's halfway between 3 and 4 cells, and that's impossible. Are you sure it's not a 2-cell lithium?

Comment: Also the service life of lead-acid is only 3-5 years in that size, so if it's older than that, don't waste too much time on it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Hi, Re: "*Your voltages don't make much sense as a lead-acid battery*" FYI those charging voltages are typical of the range for small 6 V SLA batteries. For example, this [battery image](https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-tn5ap676mi/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/184371/175606/ap-640__98927.1552934160.jpg) from [atbatt.com](https://www.atbatt.com/amstron-ap-640f1-6v-4ah-sla-battery-f1-terminal-close-out-item/) (just a random example image). So IMHO the OP's question does make sense for a 6 V SLA battery. Yes, completely agree about battery service life concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a point, easiest way is to connect this panel directly to battery via 4.7 ohm power resistor *(12v-6v)/1A=6ohm* which will limits the current. A series diode is also necessary so energy does not flow from battery back to panel during night/cloud. The battery needs an overvoltage protection to cut the charging once reaches 7.2v.

All together can be really easy done according this schematic:
(a cheap P-mos in TO220 package with enough Vds (>30v) can be used)
[image]

Blue is battery voltage, green is charging current.

[image]

**Edit:**
A more efficient in cloudy days where the limiting resistor would couse an unwanted losses at the expense of batt. charging is to use a transistor current limiter. A limiter is set to around 1A and cut-off voltage to about 7.2V. Q3 must be a power transistor like BDxxx.

[image]

[image]

Green is battery voltage, red is charging current.

Comment: Nice (pěkný). However, for a small load voltage of 6V a Si diode drop represents  ~10% loss to begin with. I realize that without a DC-DC convertor we cannot get even close to MPTT tracking in varying light conditions. That way your design may fit the bill. Otherwise I would suggest another MOSFET in a role of an *ideal diode*.